# Creating a function from a variable

Tags: php

I am attempting to run a function named from a variable.  There is no syntax error.  Temperature is not returned.  I don't know for certain if the problem is with the function itself or the eval.  Variations on the eval theme have not worked so far.

```
function getBtemp($lum, $sub){
    $tempsB = array(
         "V" => array( 30000, 25400, ... ),
         "III" => array( 29000, 24000, ... ),
         "I" => array( 26000, 20800, ... ) );
    if($lum == "VI"){ $lum = "V"; }
    else if($lum == "IV"){ $lum = "III"; }
    else if($lum == "II" || $lum == "Ib" || $lum == "Ia" ){ $lum = "V"; }
    return $tempsB['$lum']['$sub']; }

// Variables:

$spectralclass = "B";
$luminosityclass = "V";
$subclass = 5;

// Needed:

$temp = getBtemp($luminosityclass, $subclass);

// Functions are named from spectral class, e.g. get.$spectralclass.temp()
// Attempt:

$str = "$temp = get".$spectralclass."temp($luminosityclass, $subclass);";
eval($str);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this:

```
$func = 'get'.$spectralclass.'temp';

$temp = $func($luminosityclass, $subclass);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might be better off doing something like

```
$functionName = 'get' . $spectralclass . 'temp';
$temp = $functionName($luminosityclass, $subclass);
```

This is what the PHP manual calls a ["variable function"](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php).  In most cases PHP lets you treat a string variable as a function name, and doing so is a bit safer (more restrictive, less error-prone) than `eval`.

Comment: I was half way through writing this with a big explanation as to why `eval` was a bad idea.  But anyway +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass parameters after set function name. See a sample:

```
function getAtemp($a = 'default') {
    echo $a;
}

$name = 'Trest';
$function = 'A';

$temp = 'get' . $function . 'temp';

echo($temp('teste'));
```

Additionally, read from Eric Lippert: [Eval is Evil](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/11/01/53329.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following line:

```
$str = "$temp = get".$spectralclass."temp($luminosityclass, $subclass);";
```

by

```
$str = '$temp = get'.$spectralclass.'temp($luminosityclass, $subclass);';
```

or

```
$str = "\$temp = get".$spectralclass."temp(\$luminosityclass, \$subclass);";
```

See http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double